# windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) won't boot up, I've tried system repair startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I've been trying to get my computer to boot up in the last 2 hours. I've tried using the system repair at start up, but all that does is it sends me to a screen with the stock Windows background that is enlarged with a cursor on the screen. It's not frozen and I can move the cursor around, but there is nothing to click on. I've tried to get into Task Manager and such, but the shortcut doesn't work. I have no back ups of the OS as it came pre-installed on the computer. Is there anyway for me to get my computer to work (I don't mind starting fresh)? I do have access to another computer but it's my brothers and it has Windows XP (I'd like to keep my Windows 7).

Comment: Have you tried booting to a Windows 7 installation disk to get to the repair tools.  Because the system repair console should have been offered, since its not offered, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound but thats the thing I don't have a Window 7 installation disc as the OS came pre-installed :(

Comment: Say if I create a "system repair disc" on a Windows 7 32-bit machine would it still work on my 64 bit??

Comment: A system repair disk made by a 32-bit operating system is not compatible with a 64-bit operatng system. It also has to be Windows 7, the repair disk for Windows XP is different from Windows 7 which is diffrent From Windows 8.0 which is different from Windows 8.1

Comment: Have you tried running in Safe Mode and disabling any startup programs? Scan for viruses? System restore?

Comment: You kind of forgot to describe the problem. You say that Windows won't boot up, but you also say that you "tried using system repair at start up", which presumably means that something happens when you boot up that gives you some options. But you don't tell us precisely what. You also give us no problem history, so we have no idea how your computer got this way, which leaves us with no way to know what the issue might be. Did this suddenly start happen one day to a machine that was working fine minutes before? Did it crash while running and then not restart? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a Windows 7/64 ISO from DigitalRiver and make a bootable DVD or USB.

Using that Windows 7/64 installation DVD/USB you can run Start-Up Repair (up to 3 consecutive runs with rebooting after each run until no error).

See [details for obtaining Windows 7 ISO and repair steps](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindows7Booting.html).

If Start-Up Repair from DVD/USB cannot fix the problem then you could save your personal files to another DVD/USB and reinstall Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

Tried booting in the safe mode using the F8 key(might differ from systems to systems) and create a bootable usb from there. After that you can go ahead and reinstall windows.